# Can I get jquery file upload to work through ajax to amazon s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

So, I am trying to get jquery file upload to work with amazon s3.

Actually, the upload IS working. The file uploads perfectly fine. But, the issue is, at the end of the request I receive the following error. This is in firefox.

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{230dddca-13b5-4268-a9d4-4f4dcbbc8a0e} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I do not get an error at all in chrome. Has anyone come across this, and if so, have you remedied it?

Amazon s3 CORS setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not sure which language you are writing your backend. However, I fixed this by including a property called 'success_action_status' and setting it as a string "201" in the policy. I also had to include the same parameter in the XHR upload form to S3.

You can read up about valid properties here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

However, it says setting the default should just return a blank response which should be perfectly valid. I think Firefox is expecting an XML response (bug w/ Firefox?), but is receiving an empty document in which it cannot parse. Setting "success_action_status" to "201", returns an XML document ready for parsing.

Hope this helps!

Justin

**Note**: make sure your "201" is truly a string when it gets encoded into your policy. I had an issue w/ PHP in which it was defaulting the value to integer, which then resulted in yet another Amazon error which returned a 403.